# How to add numbers to typing rules?

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm writing my thesis, and I want to be able to reference equation numbers. However, I have used the `mathpartir` package to format my equations as they are rules for typing derivations, but there doesn't seem to be an option to allow me to number the equations I produce using this package. I have tried wrapping it in an `equation` environment, and it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

In order to try and achieve this, I have tried the following LaTeX code:

```
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\inferrule*[Right=float]
{ }
{\Gamma \vdash \texttt{num}: \texttt{float[n]}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and it has rendered the equation properly, but it isn't numbered.

Comment: Since you are not providing any code for others to test, how are we suppose to help?

Comment: I can't provide any code because there isn't any. I could add something showing what I'm currently doing, but that probably wouldn't help.

Comment: As you can see from other questions in the site, you are unlikely to get any help without providing any code that others can use. For example I've never used `mathpartir` so I have no idea how you use it. And especially I don;t know how **you** are using it or what you have tried to add equation numbers.

Comment: I edited my question with an MWE.

Comment: Adding a `\documentclass{article}` to the beginning of your code, I get a result which has an equation number at the right margin.

Comment: I was using `\documentclass{report}` because that gives me the ability to use `\chapter`, unless there's a way to have chapters in an article.